# bobj report to power bi. In bobj I have a calculation as = Max(IF([Replicate = 1] Then ([Result])) In ([Batch ID])

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Sample Data

| Batch ID | Result value | Replicate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 817 | 2.93 | 1 |
| 817 | 2.85 | 2 |
| 821 | 3.02 | 1 |
| 821 | 2.94 | 2 |

Expected result

| Batch ID | Result value | Replicate | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 817 | 2.93 | 1 | 2.93 |
| 817 | 2.85 | 2 | 2.93 |
| 821 | 3.02 | 1 | 3.02 |
| 821 | 2.94 | 2 | 3.02 |

Tried using this

```
Value = IF([Replicate = 1, [Result], Calculate(Max([Result])))
```

But not getting expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Value = IF([Replicate] = 1,
  [Result value],
  CALCULATE( MAX([Result value]), ALLEXCEPT('yourTable','yourTable'[Batch ID] ) )
)
```

Comment: I have tried this but not getting correct results.

Comment: This answer works as expected. If it doesn't work as expected then be respectful and share in what way it doesn't work. Also look to write clearer questions.